# Deploy active directory on poor network

Tags: networking, active-directory

Situation is I have about 100+ pc and deploy over 50+ locations.

We don't have local server on each location. And some locations have poor network.

Is it possible to deploy active directory? And what will happen on poor network locations.

Comment: what is a poor network? unorganized, slow, unstable?

Comment: @pacey, the way I read his question, suggests makes me think he is talking about unreliable connectivity.

Comment: what AD services do you plan on using?  Is this just for  authentication?  Do you plan on using group policies to control the computers?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but there are certain safeguards that you should take to account for disconnected users if their connections are unreliable.

- If you are using file shares you'll want to configure Offline Files so that the users aren't impacted if a link is down.
- You'll want to make sure Windows caches some login credentials so that users can log in. The default is to cache the last 10 logons, I believe.
- If you are using Group Policy, you'll want to make the group policy processing timeout something sane so that users are able to receive policy updates over their slow link, including software installations if you choose to use that.

Comment: I'd shy away from software deployments using Group Policy on unreliable network connections though.

Comment: @TristanK Completely agreed. In some cases it's nearly unavoidable. I'd definitely advise the OP to use this sparingly.